# Accessing asp.net mvc routing table in an http module

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc

Is it possible to access the routing table in an HttpModule.

But, in fact, more specifically is it possible to programatically figure out which route was taken?

Answer (score 2):

[Glimpse](http://GetGlimpse.com) will also show you which route was selected, and it's source will also show you how to get access to the currently selected route.

Answer (score 1):

Technically this is possible.
Check out Haack's Route Debugger code. It may help you gain insight into how to accomplish this for your specific needs.

http://haacked.com/archive/2008/03/13/url-routing-debugger.aspx 
Not only can you get this bits to this, it is also a nuget package as well.

I think this will point you in the right direction to get started.